# How to get the player with maximum points in a Java hashmap

Tags: java

I am trying to beat a sololearn challenge where we store the name of a player in a hashmap and then I am needed to iterate through the values of each player hashmap and get the name of the player with the highest score. I have been given a template code but do not have any idea on how to complete the class Bowling with a method called getWinner() to get the name of the player with the maximum points please help

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Bowling {
    HashMap<String, Integer> players;
    Bowling() {
        players = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
    public void addPlayer(String name, int p) {
        players.put(name, p);
    }
    //your code goes here
    void getWinner(){
     //help me complete this to get the name or the winner
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Bowling game = new Bowling();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            String[] values = input.split(" ");
            String name = values[0];
            int points = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            game.addPlayer(name, points);
        }
        game.getWinner();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is `void getWinner()` - no return value ? (bad practice IMO)

Comment: Yes asnwer can just do a system.out.println inside that method...

Comment: then it should not have been named `get...` by usual conventions getter methods are used to return a value; better would have been something like `printWinner()`  (assuming last comment was meant as reply to my previous comment)

Comment: I guess that explains why you have 78 answers with a reputation of 121

Comment: Not sure what you do mean by "that" in "that explains"...  most probably not that I marked almost all my answers as being "Community Wiki" so to not get reputation... More than half of my answers have positive score (> 0), just 3 out of 83 are negative (-1, -2, -1) ... should we check YOUR stats?

Comment: @Publius 1) are you sure it is theirs real name? 2) `user16320675` is not a fake name **¹** , it is just no name, the default on this site if you do not set a name. 3) I never said they cannot write the method as they want. 4) Again, it was just a well meant suggestion. 5) strange logic of yours: "Other people are stealing, so it is ok to steal?" || **1** it should be very clear that `user16320675`  is not even a name (btw. the number is the user ID, kind of *stronger* than just a name that can be changed at will)

Comment: @Publius speaking of fake name: "Timothy" or "Publius" or ... !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `entrySet` (key, value), use a `Comparator` and compare them by the value and use `Collections.max()` to get the highest value. After this just get the key and you have the player name:

```java
Collections.max(players.entrySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all key from a map with `keySet()` and so get the values associated to the key. So here a key would be the name of a player and the values is score.
So here is a simple answer if there is no tie :).

```
        void getWinner(){
        int currentBestScore = 0;
        String currentWinner = "nobody"
        for ( String playerName : players.keySet() ) {
            if(players.get(playerName)>=currentBestScore){
                 currentWinner = playerName;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(playerName);
}
```